# Require second login for users on Django based site

Tags: django

I have a Django 2.2 based project that uses a custom user model, the built-in Auth app and Django-All-Auth for user management. Almost every page on the site is behind a login and we use varying levels of permissions to determine what can be accessed a user.

So far, so good, but now I'm being asked to designate everything behind a specific part of the site as "sensitive", requiring a second login prompt using the same login credentials. What this means is that the client wants to see a login appear when they try to access anything under `/top-secret/` the first time in a set time, say 30 mins, regardless of whether they're already logged in or not.

I've dug around on the internet for ideas on how to do this, but so far I've been unable to find a good solution. Has anyone here had any experience with something similar, and if so, could they point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want them to provide their user specific login details again or another set of credentials?

Comment: We'd prefer to use the same credentials. I'll update the question.

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like this, https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/privacy.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to make this work in my situation. I debated deleting this question, but on the off chance that there's someone else out there that wants to do something similar, here's how I did it.

Create a new middleware with the following:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone


class ExtraLoginPromptMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            for url in settings.EXTRA_LOGIN_URLS:
                if request.path.startswith(url):
                    last_seen = request.session.get(settings.EXTRA_LOGIN_SESSION_VARIABLE)
                    if not last_seen:
                        last_seen = request.user.last_login
                    else:
                        last_seen = datetime.fromisoformat(last_seen)

                    if last_seen + relativedelta(seconds=settings.EXTRA_LOGIN_EXPIRY) < timezone.now():
                        # NB, this uses allauth, if you want to use django.auth, just
                        # call django.contrib.auth's logout instead
                        get_adapter(request).logout(request)
                        return redirect('{}?next={}'.format(reverse('account_login'), url))
                    else:
                        request.session[settings.EXTRA_LOGIN_SESSION_VARIABLE] = timezone.now().isoformat()

        return self.get_response(request)
```

To make use of this, you'll want to add this middleware after `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware`

You'll also want to define a few variables in your settings:

```
EXTRA_LOGIN_URLS = ['/top-secret/', 'another-secret']
EXTRA_LOGIN_EXPIRY = 120  # How long before the "extra security" session expires
EXTRA_LOGIN_SESSION_VARIABLE = 'extra-login-last-seen'
```